# Colorbox isnt working?

Tags: colorbox

I´ve got a problem with the jQuery colorbox.

```
$('a[data-lightbox]').map(function() {
      $(this).colorbox({
        loop:false,
        rel:$(this).attr('data-lightbox'),
        opacity: '0.6'
      })
        $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
```

Somehow the colorbox wont open but I dont know why:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lgdez0dn/7/

Tanks for the help